# Getting HTTP 404 Not Found when issuing POST using curl

Tags: java, json, curl, jersey, http-post

I am trying to pass a JSON string to a POST method via a curl command. However, i am receiving a HTTP 1.1 404 Not Found error. I am trying to create a simple web service which will have the JSON string passed to it to populate a mysql db.

Here is my DAO class which is used to do the GETS and the POSTS.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class PersonDAO {

 public List<Person> findAll() {
        List<PErson> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
        Connection c = null;
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM person ORDER BY firstName";
        try {
            c = ConnectionHelper.getConnection();
            Statement s = c.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                list.add(processRow(rs));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            ConnectionHelper.close(c);
        }
        return list;

    public Person create(Person person) {
        Connection c = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            c = ConnectionHelper.getConnection();
            ps = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Person (firstName,lastName) VALUES (?, ?)",
                new String[] { "ID" });
            ps.setString(1, person.getfirstName());
            ps.setString(2,person.getlastName());
            ps.executeUpdate();
            ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
            rs.next();
            int id = rs.getInt(1);
            person.setId(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            ConnectionHelper.close(c);
        }
        return person;
    }
 protected Person processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setfirstName(rs.getString("firstname"));
        person.setlastName(rs.getString("lastname"));
        return person;
    }
```

My POJO

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Person{
  private Integer id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  //GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

My Person Resource class for my annotations:

```
@Path("/people")
public class PersonResource{
PersonDAO dao = new PersonDAO();

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Person> findAll(){
  System.out.println("findAll");
  return dao.findAll();
}

@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Person creare(Person person){
  System.out.println("creating person");
  return dao.create(person);
}
```

When i issue the GET curl command it works fine and It returns all the values in the person table. However, if I issue a POST curl command I get the following error :

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1025
Date: Thu, 27 Dec 2012 01:33:41 GMT

<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.32 - Error report</title><style> [...]
```

Kindly let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: (IMO the DAO code isn't relevant at this point. More useful would be the precise curl commands you're using, being explicit about the framework, etc.)

Comment: @Srinivas, thanks for the info.. my curl command is something like this : curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Doe"}' http://localhost:8080/persondb/rest/people

Comment: @california6586 and what is the curl command that you are using for `GET` which is working fine?

Comment: Hi Srinivas, here is my GET curl command which works just fine :curl -i -X GET http://localhost:8080/persondb/rest/people

Answer (score 3):

I assume you must be missing **-H 'Content-Type:application/json'** in the command you issue.

Comment: Hi Fud..thanks for the response..I am not missing the Content-Type:aplication/json.. this is my curl command :curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Doe"}' localhost:8080/persondb/rest/people

Answer (score 2):

In the POST before method, add PATH,try it.

Comment: Please expand on your answer.

Comment: Hello Credo, I assumed that you meant that I add a PATH annotation before my POST method. I tried that and now I get the HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed error...

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly same problem and figured out it's related to Spring Security. Increase the logging level of spring security in your logging library with something similar to following:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.security.web: DEBUG
```

After that, when you send your request you can see what is the last filter executed on the filter chain. In my case it was CsrfProtectionFilter. I disabled it and it worked.

If that doesn't help, also try enabling the tracing of your REST framework. That can also give you a clue. You can do it in jersey by following:

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put(ServerProperties.TRACING, "ALL");
this.addProperties(map);
```